# IOS13 beta 5: Does SKProductsRequest supposed to work on simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, storekit, ios13

Though everything works great on actual devices, I wonder why the delegate is never called back **on simulator on iOS 13 beta 5**?

I searched the internet for an answer, but found nothing.

I implemented the 3 functions for the protocol as follows:

```
public class StoreKit {
    var request: SKProductsRequest? = nil   // Keep a strong reference

    public func fetchProducts() {
        print("\(#function): start fetching products")

        let r = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs)
        request = r
        r.delegate = self
        r.start()
    }

}

// MARK: - Get the requested products

extension StoreKit: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    /// Products are received
    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("\(#function): did receive")
    }



    /// Unable to received the products
    public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("\(#function): Error for request: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }



    public func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
        print("\(#function): did finish")
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue here with iOS 13 simulator devices on Beta 5. Will check on Beta 6 and report back.

Comment: Same issue on Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) but on the iPad simulator only :/

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020258/requesting-an-in-app-purchase-in-ios-13-fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue has been fixed by Apple in Xcode beta 6 (August 16th, 2019).

*[UPDATE Sept 30th 2019]*

For those who's still experience the issue, did you download Xcode v11.1 (11A1027), Released on September 24, 2019? I don't have any issue with it. If you still, try to add some information so that I can help you further.

Comment: In Xcode 11 GM when I request products on simulator I get a `request:didFailWithError:` with error message being:
`Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=507 "Error decoding object" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error decoding object, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Attempted to decode store response}`

Comment: A second Xcode 11 GM Seed has been released. Try that one.

Comment: I confirm the issue still exist with xcode 11 release Version 11.0 (11A420a)

Comment: Same issue on Xcode 11.1 (11A1027) but on the iPad simulator only :/

Comment: Same error on Xcode 11.2 (11B52).  Is there still no resolution for this?

Comment: Same error on Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500) on iPad simulator and my app is still getting rejected.

Comment: Same error on Xcode 11.3 on iPad simulator and my app is still getting rejected.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample? One (temporary?) workaround seems to switch to iOS13 target.

Comment: Same error on Xcode 13.3 on iPhone Simulator with iOS 13.3.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, as mentioned in the comments to the author's answer.

(
`request:didFailWithError: with error message being: Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=507 "Error decoding object" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error decoding object, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Attempted to decode store response}`
)

I changed project's iOS deployment target to iOS 13.0 and products loaded successfully in a simulator.

Comment: In my case, using xcode 11 release Version 11.0 (11A420a), the problem still exists even after selecting iOS 13.0 as deployment target and cleaning.

Comment: I'm also still getting this error after setting the deployment target to 13.0.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 11.2 (11B52) iOS 13.2 Simulator **working** for me

As mentioned in almost all suggestions to related issues- make sure you have fully completed setting up the product, eg an in-app purchase. Most importantly make sure your Agreements, Tax, and Banking section has been completed 100%:

1. Go to App Store Connect
2. Select Agreements, Tax, and Banking
3. Under Agreement tab, make sure Free and Paid apps agreements show **Active** status
4. Make sure you have filled all the required information on the remaining tabs.
5. If in any of those tabs you are still seeing empty fields, or fields in which you can enter information, it means you are not done yet.

To quickly test your app's purchasable products you can use [Apple's sample In app purchase example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases). You do need to give it your app's Bundle Id and list out the purchasable product id in a specific file. All instructions are there.

As of the date of this post, simulator SKProductsRequest is working perfectly.

[image]